# handle ios system pop ups

Tags: ios, popup, appium, appium-ios

I have to have handle system pop up on `iOS`. I have tried below solution but they do not help:
`1. driver.findElement(By.name("OK")).click();`
`2. capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);`

These solution do not help.

I went through http://bitbar.com/appium-tip-9-how-to-automatically-dismiss-dialogs-and-autoaccept-alerts/ which says to use image recognition to handle alerts. 
Is there any solution which can help me handle these pop-ups. Or if anyone is aware of any script which can be called at time of popup appearance to handle these pop ups.

Also, I came to know that appium can handle system pop-ups for ios 10. Is there any solution for lower versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `appium 1.6.3` and tested for handling ios system pop ups and I was able to click on Install button for one of the pop up using `element.click()` method.